# Access local directory image from web app running in jetty

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty

My web application is written using jsp/javascripts. Backend Java. Have managed to implement the code to save an image outside webapplication, because I dont want to save the images in webapp/images folder(because when the server is down and when rebuild the app, I lose those saved images). What I want is to access those images I saved in my local directory again from my web app but I dont know how to. How can I access my local folder from jetty server, and jetty server is running on the same local machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the path to `/image` to store & read files by

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");
```

Even you can read the file from external location from your servlet

```
    File image = new File("d:\\image\1.jpg");
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        // Open streams.
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(image), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        // Write file contents to response.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        // Gently close streams.
        close(output);
        close(input);
    }
```

**Also See**

- [Image Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Comment: lets say that my image is at D:/images folder and I am running jetty server in the same machine. How can I access my that local folder (D:/images)?